# Should we allow questions regarding a specific physics journal?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was thinking of asking a question not directly related to physics, but to a physics journal. Do you guys think these kind of questions should be allowed?

**Examples:**

Is there a .tex template for submissions to [said journal]?

Would [said-journal] accept a submission about [subject]? (where subject is similar but not exactly one of the jounrnal's areas)

What's the correct (journal name) abbreviation to use when citing a paper from [said journal]?

Comment: It could be interesting but maybe not "on topic". How is related your question with a physics journal? On the other hand, there are a lot of questions regarding journals in MathOverflow http://mathoverflow.net/search?q=journal

Comment: Could you put an example or two in the question?

Comment: The second question sounds good. However, regarding the first question I think you would get a much better advice visiting the *Author Guidelines Page*, *Guidelines for Authors*, etc or contacting directly the journal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a .tex template for submissions to [said journal]?

As Robert commented, you'd probably want to contact the journal. If you don't get anything from them, you could ask at tex.SE. I don't think it belongs here though.

> Would [said-journal] accept a submission about [subject]? (where subject is similar but not exactly one of the jounrnal's areas)

I think that's okay (as long as the journal is a physics journal of course).

> What's the correct (journal name) abbreviation to use when citing a paper from [said journal]?

hm... now that isn't really about physics at all, although it is of interest to physicists. I think this is similar to the first one - it wouldn't go at tex.SE, of course, but I think if we allow the first one it'd make sense to allow this, and if we don't allow the first one it'd make sense not to allow this.

Comment: Actually, I don't think tex.SE would be of much help regarding the first question. If the journal is not helpful, the asker would be in a very odd situation. Now, it is more probable that somebody here could ask that question than in tex.SE, however, that doesn't mean this is a proper place to ask. Hopefully no one will have to face such situation.

Comment: @Robert: There are already a few questions of that nature on the site; see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/450. My reasoning was that if the journal can't provide a style file or template, either some third party has written one or not, and in at least the former case, the tex.SE people could tell you where to look. (generally CTAN) But you're right that it would be an odd (and relatively rare) situation in which the people at the journal can't help with that question.

Comment: Alright, seems like tex.SE could be useful (I didn't find many regarding journals or .sty files, though).

Comment: Is this answer still     applicable?

Comment: @Dimension10 mostly yes, although I'm not sure if asking "would [journal] accept a submission about [subject]?" would be okay anymore.